# jQuery dialog error when opening dialog second time - TypeError: oa is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am showing a dialog using function shown below when someone clicks on element with id mydialog. The page that is shown loads following javascripts

jquery-2.1.0.js
jquery-ui.js
highcharts/js/highcharts.js

( highchart is graphing library )

This all works beautifully when someone click on element with id mydialog. but when someone click on that element second time I see following error.

```
TypeError: oa is not a function
if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" ) {
```

What am I doing wrong,

[ it appears that when second time dialog opens jQuery is not initialized before highchart tries to access some methods? ]

What cleanup if anything am I missing when user clocks the dialog?

```
$(function(){
        $('.mydialog').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('<div/>', {'class':'myDlgClass', 'id':'link-'+($(this).index()+1) }).
            load($(this).attr('href')).appendTo('body').dialog({
                title: 'MyDialog',
                width: 700,
                height: 375,
                modal: true,
                close: function() {
                    id_to_remove = 'link-'+($(this).index()+1)
                    alert("Destroy Dialog " + id_to_remove);
                    $(id_to_remove).remove();
                    //$(this).dialog('destroy');
                }
            });
        });
});
```

The html page that gets opened is uses following javascript

I have two jsFiddle trying to re-create problem but I am coming across CORS issue

This is content of the dialog

http://jsfiddle.net/snijsure/6v0ozwt6/

This is to open dialog
http://jsfiddle.net/snijsure/fgb8cvtv/

Comment: please share jsfiddle link with your problem statement.

Comment: I updated my question with pointers to jsFiddle but I am not able to link them because of CORS issue? Not sure how to do that..

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are giving  a valid input as expected.